# 'Fire & Forget' call from Sinatra

Tags: ruby, api, pdf, sinatra

I am writing an end-point using `Sinatra` where I will be receiving raw pdfs from the client and need to process the pdf for internal use. Now the pdf processing takes a while and I do not necessarily want client to wait till the processing is finished and risking a `timeout` (`504`). Instead the would like to invoke another method that handles pdf processing while I respond back to the client with appropriate code. What is the best way to implement that using Sinatra?

Comment: There are several projects implementing a job queue outside of a single request. While are often used with Rails (and most examples on the net will show rails examples), they are generally also well usable from Sinatra. Examples are [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/). That said, your question is still very broad and StackOverflow isn't well suited for broad architectural questions or finding the right tool to use. You should make your own analysis what works well for you.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a few parts to this, so let me break down the various steps that are going to happen:

- Client uploads a PDF file: depending on the size of the PDF and the speed of their connection, this could take a while. While you're waiting for the upload your web process is busy receiving the data and is unable to process any other requests for any other clients.
- You then need to process the uploaded file, store it somewhere, possibly manipulate it somehow. If you do all that as part of the request process then there is yet more time you're tied up dealing with this one request and unable to serve other clients.

The typical way to solve the latter of those problems, manipulating or processing an uploaded asset, is to use a background job queue such as Sidekiq (http://sidekiq.org). You store the required data somewhere, keep enough information to know what to work on (e.g., the database ID of a model that has stored the relevant information, a filename, etc.), and then pass all of that required information into a background job. You then have separate worker processes that pick up that work and complete it, but they aren't part of your web process so they aren't blocking other clients from receiving information.

This still leaves us with the problem of handling large uploads, fortunately that has a solution too. Take advantage of all of the web capacity Amazon has and have the clients upload the file direct to S3, when it's complete they can post just the filename to you, and you can then queue that up into your worker from the previous step and have it all happen in the background. This blog post has a good explanation of how to wire it together using Paperclip http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and